# Convergence in L^p and convergence in norm

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

I am trying to show these two statements:

Let $(\mathbb R^n,\mathcal M,m)$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure and $\mathcal M$ are the Lebesgue measurable sets, and let $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ and $f$ in $L^p(\mathbb R^n)$ for $1 \leq p < \infty$.

(a) $||f_n-f||_{L^p} \to 0 \implies ||f_n||_{L^p(\mathbb R^n)} \to ||f||_{L^p(\mathbb R^n)}$

(b) If $f_n \to f$ a.e. and $||f_n||_{L^p(\mathbb R^n)} \to ||f||_{L^p(\mathbb R^n)}$, then $||f_n-f||_{L^p} \to 0 $

There is a suggestion for part (b) which is to apply Fatou's lemma to the sequence $g_n(X)=2^{p-1}(|f_n(x)|^p+|f(x)|^p)-|f_n(x)-f(x)|^p$.

I'll write what I could do:

For part (b), I could not show that the suggested sequence $(g_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is non negative, so instead I've used the sequence $h_n(x)=2^p(|f_n(x)|^p+|f(x)|^p)-|f_n(x)-f(x)|^p$. To apply Fatou's lemma to this sequence let's show non-negativity of the terms:

$$|f_n(x)-f(x)|^p \leq (|f_n(x)|+|f(x)|)^p$$$$\leq 2^p\max\{|f_n(x)|,|f(x)|\}^p$$ $$\leq 2^p(|f_n(x)|^p+|f(x)|^p)$$

It follows that $h_n(x) \geq 0$. Notice that $\lim_{n \to \infty} h_n(x)=2^{p+1}|f(x)|^p$ a.e., applying Fatou's lemma we have $$\int_{\mathbb R^d} 2^{p+1}|f(x)|dx \leq \lim inf \int_{\mathbb R^d}2^p(|f_n(x)|^p+|f(x)|^p)-|f_n(x)-f(x)|^pdx$$$$=\int_{\mathbb R^d}2^p|f|^pdx+\int_{\mathbb R^d}2^p|f|^pdx-\lim sup \int_{\mathbb R^d}|f_n-f|^pdx$$

From here it follows $\lim sup \int_{\mathbb R^d}|f_n-f|^pdx=0$, so $||f_n-f||_{L^p(\mathbb R^d)}=0$.

I don't know what to do to prove (a), could someone help me with that part and tell me if my solution to (b) is correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Part (b) looks right. (a) is even simpler, and is true in any normed linear space. Just notice that $|\|f_n\| - \|f\|| \leq \|f_n - f\|$ by the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to use the hint and show that $g_n(x)$ is positive, you can use the fact that $x^p$ is convex.
\begin{align*}
\big|f_n-f\big |^p &\leq \left( |f_n|+|f|\right)^p & \text{triangle inequality}
\\ &=2^p\left( \frac{1}{2} |f_n| + \frac{1}{2}|f| \right)^p
\\ &\leq 2^{p-1}\left( |f_n|^p+|f|^p \right) & \text{convexity of $x^p$.}
\end{align*}

If you get lazy and not want to use Fatou, you can apply the generalized dominated convergence theorem.